# How do I fix my platformer collision detection?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game that allows my 2D sprite to jump on a platform but when it lands on the platform, my 2D sprite is not exactly on top of the platform, sometimes its exceeding or the same as the position of the platform.

```
//here is my code:

Texture2D jumper;
Texture2D tile;
Vector2 position, velocity;
Rectangle top;
Rectangle tile_rectangle;
Rectangle jumper_rectangle;
KeyboardState ks;

bool jump;

//here is my Load Content:

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    jump = true;
    position.X = 10;
    position.Y = 10;

    jumper = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");
    tile = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tile");

    tile_rectangle = new Rectangle(300, 350, tile.Width, tile.Height);
    top = new Rectangle(tile_rectangle.X, tile_rectangle.Y - 16, tile_rectangle.Width, 10);
}

//Here is my update:

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    ks = Keyboard.GetState();
    position += velocity;

    float i = 1;

    if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && jump == false)
    {
        position.Y -= 10f;
        velocity.Y = -25f;
        jump = true;
    }

    if (jump == true)
    {

        velocity.Y += 2f * i;
    }

    if (position.Y > 400)
    {

        jump = false;
    }

    if (jump == false)
    {
        velocity.Y = 0f;
    }

    BoundingBox();

    if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        position.X += 5f;
        velocity.X = +0.05f;

        if (jumper_rectangle.Left > tile_rectangle.Right)
        {
            jump = true;
        }
    }

    if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        position.X -= 5f;
        velocity.X = -0.05f;

        if (jumper_rectangle.Right < tile_rectangle.Left)
        {
            jump = true;
        }
    }
    jumper_rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, jumper.Width, jumper.Height);
    BoundingBox();
    base.Update(gameTime);

}

//here is my draw:

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(jumper, jumper_rectangle, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(tile, tile_rectangle, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}

//here is my method on landing:

public void BoundingBox()
{
    if (jumper_rectangle.Intersects(top))
    {
        if (jumper_rectangle.Bottom > top.Top)
        {
            position.Y--;
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Where did i go wrong or is there some other way?

Comment: how about `if(jumper_rectangle.Bottom >= top.Top) { position.Y = top.Top - 1; jump = false;}` also why check for `Intersects` the second if statement should be enough.